# flutter desktop_multi_window macos not working properly

Tags: flutter, macos

I am using [desktop_multi_window](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_multi_window) to open another window but on macos if you switch focus on something else like clicking the desktop when you come back to the second window setState does not work anymore, the build method does not get called, the only thing that works is GestureDetector. If you maximize the window then everything works properly.

Can someone help me with some workaround without having to press maximize?

```
import 'package:desktop_multi_window/desktop_multi_window.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

List<int> windowsIds = [];
void main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (args.isNotEmpty) {
    runApp(TestApp());
  } else {
    runApp(const MainApp());
  }
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                final window = await DesktopMultiWindow.createWindow();
                window
                  ..setFrame(const Offset(0, 0) & const Size(1280, 720))
                  ..center()
                  ..setTitle('title')
                  ..show();
              },
              child: Text('open window')),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestApp> createState() => _TestAppState();
}

class _TestAppState extends State<TestApp> {
  int test = 0;
  bool hide = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          hide = !hide;
          setState(() {});
        },
        child: hide
            ? Text('hidden')
            : Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(test.toString()),
                      TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            test++;
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Text('press'))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```